# цІнник чи ціннИк?

Tags: наголос, розмовна-українська

Який наголос правильний цІнник чи ціннИк, адже у [Вікісловнику](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) наголос на перший склад, а от у [Академічному тлумачному словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/cinnyk) на другий. То ж який з варіантів правильний, чи можливі обидва?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сайті [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/nagolos/nagolos-u-slovi-czinnuk) подають так:

> ЦіннИк.

На [цьому](https://ukr-lifehacks.ed-era.com/1lec/nagolos.html) сайті у рубриці "Наголос" теж подають:

> ціннИк

[Орфографічний словник](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=379433) подає аналогічну інформацію:

> ЦіннИк, іменник чоловічого роду.

Також і СУМ, наведений Вами, містить таку ж інформацію.

Отже, наголос тільки ціннИк.

Comment: Поважність джерел у запитанні — це, принаймні, один академічний словник. Поважність джерел у відповіді — це два аматорських сайти. На мою думку, у такому випадку відповідь повинна, як мінімум, ґрунтуватися на академічних джерелах, і бажано — декількох.